# PackageManager's DONT_KILL_APP flag is not working on Android Lollipop 5.0

Tags: java, android

Application has two activities: one is a Dialog, other is a fullscreen activity which implements several classes. Dialog activity has MAIN/LAUNCHER category.

Pressing Dialog button is starting fullscreen activity and then disable Dialog activity component to hide the Icon.

Disabling is done by the usual code:

```
private static final ComponentName COMPONENT_NAME = 
        new ComponentName("com.xxxx.xxxxx", "com.xxxx.xxxxx.DialogActivity");
....
....
try {
    PackageManager localPackageManager = getPackageManager();
    localPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(COMPONENT_NAME, 
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

It worked fine till I've updated to Lollipop.
Now my fullscreen activity beeing killed even if user interacts with it.
LogCat shows that `PACKAGE_CHANGED` intent is fired and then boom, app is closed.

I've tested it on two Nexuses (KitKat and Lollipop) and OnePlus (Cyanogen 11 and 12.0). Result is always the same - Lollipop kills the app.

Is there any other way to disable component? Is there a way to cheat memory optimization (I guess it's the troublemaker), so application won't be killed?